# Inserting HTML elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Instead of tediously search for workarounds for each type of attribute and event when using the following syntax:

```
elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.id = 'myID';
elem.innerHTML = ' my Text '
document.body.insertBefore(elem,document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

Is there a way where I can just declare the entire HTML element as a string? like:

```
elem = document.createElement("<div id='myID'> my Text </div>");
document.body.insertBefore(elem,document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Instead of directly messing with **`innerHTML`** it might be better to create a fragment and then insert that:

```
function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

var fragment = create('<div>Hello!</div><p>...</p>');
// You can use native DOM methods to insert the fragment:
document.body.insertBefore(fragment, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

Benefits:

1. You can use native DOM methods for insertion such as insertBefore, appendChild etc.
2. You have access to the actual DOM nodes before they're inserted; you can access the fragment's childNodes object.
3. Using document fragments is very quick; faster than creating elements outside of the DOM and in certain situations faster than innerHTML.

---

Even though **`innerHTML`** is used within the function, it's all happening outside of the DOM so it's much faster than you'd think...

Comment: I bet this createDocumentFragment() wouldn't be as good as the "legacy" innerHTML.

Comment: I really would like backward compatibility, so how could I use this alongside innerHTML, like I check if this method is not null, maybe?

Comment: This method works in all modern browsers. For IE 5.5 and below you could perform a check like:: if (document.createDocumentFragment) { create('...'); } else { /* Use innerHTML perhaps */ }

Comment: Exactly my point, thanks for the code snippet!  I like your method since its quick, so making this the default behavior on all modern browsers is preferable.

Comment: crescentfresh - anomalies... In 99% of cases it won't fail; where it does you'll have to venture another abstraction.

Comment: crescentfresh, I help on SO because I enjoy helping people; I'm sorry if a solution is not 100% operable in all situations. If you're so concerned why not offer your own solution instead of being unnecessarily critical of already-offered answers? With any abstraction there will always be edge-cases! This is a learning environment - we're not here to give people a solution on a plate - we're here to help each other become better at what we do! And sorry, but where did anyone mention "AJAX"?

Comment: Fair enough. My apologies. I just feel that there're so many abstractions on here with zero caveats mentioned.

Answer (score 98):

You want this

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<div id="myID">...</div>' );
```

Comment: @JonnyLeeds this doesn't seem to work on `body` element but works fine on any other element.

Comment: @Phill Of course it works on `<body>`. As a matter of fact, running it on `<body>` is my standard method of injecting stuff like style sheets into web pages via the console. What issue are you having?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas probably because the body element wasn't defined at execution time ... i paired your line with window.onload = function() { … } to prevent that problem

Comment: @Grandy Phill wrote that it works on other elements. If `<body>` were undefined, so would be all other elements, so this is likely not Phill’s issue.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Hmm yeah you right ... if it works on anything it should work on body too

Comment: this is great! Unfortunately, maybe because I am in a table, somehow all HTML tags are stripped from what I insert...

Answer (score 40):

Have a look at [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```
var element = document.getElementById("one");
var newElement = '<div id="two">two</div>'
element.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterend', newElement )
// new DOM structure: <div id="one">one</div><div id="two">two</div>
```

**position** is the position relative to the element you are inserting adjacent to:

**'beforebegin'** 
Before the element itself

**'afterbegin'** 
Just inside the element, before its first child

**'beforeend'**
Just inside the element, after its last child

**'afterend'**
After the element itself

Answer (score 17):

In old school JavaScript, you could do this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<p id="foo">Some HTML</p>' + document.body.innerHTML;
```

In response to your comment:

> [...] I was interested in declaring the source of a new element's attributes and events, not the `innerHTML` of an element.

You need to inject the new HTML into the DOM, though; that's why `innerHTML` is used in the old school JavaScript example. The `innerHTML` of the `BODY` element is prepended with the new HTML. We're not really touching the existing HTML inside the `BODY`.

I'll rewrite the abovementioned example to clarify this:

```
var newElement = '<p id="foo">This is some dynamically added HTML. Yay!</p>';
var bodyElement = document.body;
bodyElement.innerHTML = newElement + bodyElement.innerHTML;
// note that += cannot be used here; this would result in 'NaN'
```

Using a JavaScript framework would make this code much less verbose and improve readability. For example, jQuery allows you to do the following:

```
$('body').prepend('<p id="foo">Some HTML</p>');
```

Comment: Pretty good. But I was interested in declaring the source of a new element's attributes and events, not the innerHTML of an element.

Comment: Can I use "document.body" instead of "document.getElementsByTagName" ?? Wouldn't it be more backward compatible?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` can indeed be replaced by `document.body`, good point. However, if you want to prepend or append the new HTML to another existing element instead of the BODY, you'll have to use `document.getElementById()` and/or `document.getElementsByTagName()`; that's why I used it in the example.

Comment: $('body').insertBefore('<p id="foo">Some HTML</p>') won't work. You're not inserting the <body> before the <p>!!???

Comment: Also, your code can get very messy very quickly if you're directly adding/inserting "innerHTML"

Comment: I must've overlooked that one, JimmyP. Thanks! It's fixed now.

Comment: @JimmyP: What rubbish! The very purpose of this question is to be able to directly insert HTML as strings instead of playing around with functions to construct it, attrib by attrib, node by node, element by element.

Comment: jeremy, it's not rubbish; check out my abstraction below. All this needs is some polishing - I am not saying don't use innerHTML.

Comment: @JimmyP: I meant your point about "gets messy" is rubbish, since I *want* to edit/see the "raw" HTML!.

Comment: this detaches all event handlers and may cause memory leaks big time.

Comment: @adardesign Of course, but that is true for every possible solution to OP’s problem (i.e. setting the HTML of the entire document based on a string). Why the downvote?

Comment: @MathiasBynens what if I want to add attribute without value in this context, like tooltip `<div tooltip class="m0">..</div>`

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, which, to be fair, is fairly new and limited, the only potential issue with this technique is the fact that you are prevented from dynamically creating some table elements.

I use a form to templating by adding "template" elements to a hidden DIV and then using cloneNode(true) to create a clone and appending it as required. Bear in ind that you do need to ensure you re-assign id's as required to prevent duplication.

Answer (score 1):

As others said the convenient jQuery [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) functionality can be emulated:

```
var html = '<div>Hello prepended</div>';
document.body.innerHTML = html + document.body.innerHTML;
```

While some say it is better not to "mess" with **innerHTML**, it is reliable in many use cases, if you know this:

> If a `<div>`, `<span>`, or `<noembed>` node has a child text node that includes the characters (`&`), (`<`), or (`>`), innerHTML returns these characters as `&amp`, `&lt` and `&gt` respectively. Use `Node.textContent` to get a correct copy of these text nodes' contents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Or:

```
var html = '<div>Hello prepended</div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html)
```

`insertAdjacentHTML` is probably a good alternative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: upvoted because you pointed me at `textContent`, the solution to copying the full HTMl from one node to another :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text)
```

This is worked for me, here is details about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers, comment or vote up instead. This was used in 3 of the older answers.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to insert HTML code inside existing page's tag use [Jnerator](http://jnerator.com). This tool was created specially for this goal.

Instead of writing next code

```
    var htmlCode = '<ul class=\'menu-countries\'><li
        class=\'item\'><img src=\'au.png\'></img><span>Australia </span></li><li
        class=\'item\'><img src=\'br.png\'> </img><span>Brazil</span></li><li
        class=\'item\'> <img src=\'ca.png\'></img><span>Canada</span></li></ul>';
    var element = document.getElementById('myTag');
    element.innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

You can write more understandable structure

```
    var jtag = $j.ul({
        class: 'menu-countries',
        child: [
            $j.li({ class: 'item', child: [
                $j.img({ src: 'au.png' }),
                $j.span({ child: 'Australia' })
            ]}),
            $j.li({ class: 'item', child: [
                $j.img({ src: 'br.png' }),
                $j.span({ child: 'Brazil' })
            ]}),
            $j.li({ class: 'item', child: [
                $j.img({ src: 'ca.png' }),
                $j.span({ child: 'Canada' })
            ]})
        ]
    });
    var htmlCode = jtag.html();
    var element = document.getElementById('myTag');
    element.innerHTML = htmlCode;
```