# body.innerHTML before/after nth-child

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, css-selectors

Is it possible to add something with innerHTML before/after the nth child of `<body>`?

e.g.:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="first">First</div>
<div id="second">Second<div id="second_sub"></div></div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can add at the beginning with `body.innerHTML = html + body.innerHTML` and at the end with `body.innerHTML += html` but how to add, for example, before the second `<div>`?

I don't want to use replace on `<div id="second">` as the source changes and the insert should be done at random. Is there a solution with innerHTML or do I need to switch to Dom Nodes? Would be slow in old browsers :(

Comment: I would have an empty div and then put the stuff inside, but I once heard that having empty tags is a bad CEO practice

Comment: Look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I'm not sure if this can be used in other browsers.

Comment: @ajax333221 You mean like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/814649/318765 ? Looks like a good option for me. Other ideas?

Comment: "Would be slow in old browsers"?! Dom functions is faster for such operations, than innerHTML even in IE6. Even if insertion of first node is slower 2-5 times, DOM insertion work with the same speed, whilst working with html string will force browser to parse and re-create all child DOM nodes each time.

Comment: @ kirilloid You are wrong: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this by now (Thanks to ajax333221):

```
e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = '<div>... huge content with several sub elements ...</div>';
document.body.insertBefore(e, document.body.childNodes[2]);
```

This is a combination of both techniques. With this I'm able to use the fast .innerHTML without extremely blowing up the code with createElement(), setAttribute(), etc.

Other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the [insertBefore method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp). It will insert a child before the given element. Alternatively there's the [appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) method which will always push elements on the beginning of the given element.
Examples:

```
<body>
    <span id="elem1">Hello</span>
    <span id="elem2">World</span>
</body>
```

Let's assume we're inserting a new element stored in the `var newElem`:
`document.insertBefore(newElem, document.getElementById("elem2"))` will give:

```
<body>
    <span id="elem1">Hello</span>
    <!-- New element here! -->
    <span id="elem2">World</span>
</body>
```

`document.appendChild(newElem)` will give:

```
<body>
    <!-- New element here! -->
    <span id="elem1">Hello</span>
    <span id="elem2">World</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Generally, MDN is a [better](http://w3fools.com) resource than w3shools: [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).

Comment: As I said: I don't want to use DOM nodes as this could extremly blow up the code. But a solution would be the combination of both. I will post an answer.