# Add to DOM without jQuery

Tags: javascript

This should be simple, but it's not.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].document.createTextNode( document.createElement('<div>some HTML</div>') );
```

It creates as a text node. How do I do it so I simply add HTML without jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting HTML elements with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814564/inserting-html-elements-with-javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Close, but no cigar. You have to create the element manually (via [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)), and *then* append it, like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "some HTML";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
```

Unfortunately, you can't do this in a one-liner because there's no function to set the `innerHTML` property of an element, which means it isn't chainable. With a bit of preparation you can make this possible, though:

```
function setInnerHTML(element, content) {
    element.innerHTML = content;
    return element;
} 

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(setInnerHTML(document.createElement("div"), "some HTML"));
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Any idea how to delete exactly the created element later (separate part of the script)?

Comment: Sure. Since we've stored a reference to the element `div` already, we can just do this: `div.parentNode.removeChild(div);`

Comment: You _can_ do it in a one-liner because `appendChild` _is_ chainable: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(document.createElement("div")).innerHTML = "some HTML";`. Long line though.

Answer (score 5):

[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) rather than createTextNode

Answer (score 1):

There're a lot of methods:

```
elem.innerHTML = ''   // fast
elem.appendChild()    
elem.insertAdjacentElement()  //fast    
elem.insertAdjacentHTML()
elem.insertAdjacentText()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.innerHTML+=document.createElement('div').outerHTML;
```