# Include php file with html via js include

Tags: php, javascript, html, include, wrapper

Ok so I am tasked to work with this third party vendor that shows movie times on their end. We have the chance to co-brand our site on their end, so in order to do that we need to create a wrapper of our site so that the movie times can show inside the wrapper so it still looks like your on our site. One option is to have a header and footer included via js external file, that way we can make changes on our side and the updates will show on their side, so we dont have to send them a new header/footer every time we make updates to the wrapper. They suggested we do it this way:

```
<script src="http://oursite.com/header.php"></script>
<script src="http://oursite.com/footer.php"></script>
```

So I have raw html in header.php hosted on our side and then I added this in the header before anything else:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>
```

However when the page loads I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xml
```

Im assuming there is a problem having raw html code in a js file? If so is there anyway around this?

Comment: Get rid of the HTML. JavaScript files are for JavaScript.

Comment: I think there is no need to use `header('')`.

Comment: Cant quite get my head around what your doing, their site links to a script that you control that modifies their site to make it look like yours? sounds a little scary.

Comment: @Blender is right what you really want?

Comment: @imsiso: I'm not really sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: @Blender all I'm trying to say is how can I help.But my English is not good so I think that's why you are angry ha?

Comment: the error is becouse you are saying the document is javascript but you are sending xhtml make a wraper so you code get stored on a variable they (your partner) can inject later in their site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a link to proper `javascript` that push desired html to the page.

```
<script src="http://oursite.com/[somejsfile].js"></script>
```

You can get help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814649/329712) on how to insert html elements using javascript

Comment: not nesesary, if the content has a mime type of text/javascript or similar it will run, the extencion meean nothing in this case

Comment: Yes it will work, but it should contain javascript code instead of html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use javascript to call an external file you need to use ajax. The problem then lies that you are taking about your site and that cannot be done when your domains do not match.

If you do it in the manner you have included you must declare the html in javascript variables then, on load push the data to where it needs to go.

```
 var html = '<html> YOUR CODE WATCH OUT FOR SINGLE QUOTES </html>';
 //check for load with jquery
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#header").html(html);
 })
```

Comment: but I think that's not correct. because of `xhtml`.(you have multiple html tags).

Comment: you could store the content in a variable and the parner can latter take the value of the variable an inject it on thier site