# Unescape HTML string from database on twig template

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I'm trying to convert a description, which is a string from my database, into HTML. I'm getting the description with `{{ projet.description }}`, but it seems that in JavaScript, "description" causes a bug in my script... So I create a div with my description on it, make it invisible, and get it with `innerHTML`.

Twig code

```
    <div id="desc">{{ projet.description }}</div>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var desc = document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML|e('js')|raw;
            document.write(desc);
        </script>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#descr {
    display:none;
}
```

But now, `document.write()` still returns a string like "`<p><em>POKEMON</em></p>`". However, I want it in HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/814649/1524085 maybe this will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost sure that HTML was escaped, so try it out:

```
<div id="desc">{{ projet.description|raw }}</div>
```

See **raw** filter on twig docs: [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)

> The raw filter marks the value as being "safe", which means that in an
>   environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be
>   escaped if raw is the last filter applied to it

Also:

```
var desc = document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML|e('js')|raw;
```

The above snippet is not valid on twig because it isn't surrounded by valid delimiters such as "`{{ }}`" or "`{% %}`".

Comment: Omg thanks for your help ! It works ! I knew that it was because of the HTML when I look at the src code, it wasn't HTML.