# Use JavaScript to Dynamically Insert an HTML Tag Between Other Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just can't figure this one out.  I have a link:

```
<a class="nav-link modalNavLinks"" href="#resA" id="resourceLinkA"><span>A</span></a>
```

I want to insert an HTML heading tag between the span tag, like this:

```
<a class="nav-link modalNavLinks"" href="#resA" id="resourceLinkA"><span><h6>A</h6></span></a>
```

And I want this to happen when the link is hovered over.  I have this javascript code which works for adding and removing style elements when the link is hovered over, but I can't figure out how to insert and HTML tag element.  Here is my JavaScript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("span").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("align-top", "text");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("align-baseline", "text");
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814564/inserting-html-elements-with-javascript

Comment: inserting html and removing on hover seems like a BAD idea. Just use CSS and change the rules you need....

Comment: @mhodges insert is wrong, it would be wrap, but still a bad idea

Comment: Agreed with epascarello, it looks like you're just wanting to change the style of the text based on hover state. Manipulate the CSS, rather than creating/deleting elements

Comment: Why do you need `h6` only on hover? Just style that `span` like it's `h6`

Comment: @epascarello Not really, that would wrap the entire span. You would probably be just better off setting the `.html()` in this case, now that I have looked at it.

Comment: @mhodges `.wrapInner()`

Comment: @epascarello Ah, yeah `wrapInner` would work for sure. But, agreed - it's still not the right way to go. Styling with CSS is a far better idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to change the span to an h6. Just add alter the CSS of the span on hover of the link. Change whatever properties you want so it matches the styles of your h6.

```css
a.nav-link:hover span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="#resA" id="resourceLinkA"><span>A</span></a>
```

If you really want to do what you are after, you want to use [`.wrapInner()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) and [`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/), but it is not a best practice to do that.

EDIT:

With the comment, it sounds like that when you added an h6, some other CSS you were applying started to work. Difference with an h6 and a span is block vs inline. So sounds like you need to set `display: block` in the css.

```css
a.nav-link:hover span {
  vertical-align: super
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">a<span>One</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">b<span>Two</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">c<span>Three</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know, I have tried that, problem is I need the text to Super script, and no amount of CSS I tried worked for that.  The 'vertical-align: super !important;' just had no effect, but by accident I noticed that adding a h6 tag had the effect I was looking for.

Comment: Well than what you need to do instead is set the the display to be a block element and not an inline one.

Comment: Love to see an example of that

Comment: add `display:block` in the css above?

Comment: closer, now I have this CSS: 'nav-item > modalNavLinks > a.active {
    color: #85a3b6;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #0072bc;
    display: block;
    color: red;
}' but the text is sub scripted, not super scripted

Comment: Really hard to help you without code that shows the real issue.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I'll put a fuller example on JSFiddle - you've been very helpful and it's much appreciated

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle Example - https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/aq9Laaew/283775/ - I had to use a simplified example because the full code is just way too much to explain

Comment: So all you want it the text to move to the top? Than remove the padding on top. `.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover { padding-top: 0; }`

Comment: You are a genius - I bless your horns with the fullness of Mother Earth!  it works!

Comment: Add that to your answer and I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

This works but in a weird way and now I do not have time. It seems when the text changes, the cursor is outside and triggers the other event.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("span").hover(function () {
        
        let spanEl =document.querySelector('#resourceLinkA span')
        let text = spanEl.innerText;
        let newEl = document.createElement('h1');
        newEl.innerText = text;
        spanEl.innerText = '';
        spanEl.appendChild(newEl);
        
    }, function () {
        
        let spanEl =document.querySelector('#resourceLinkA span')
        spanEl.innerHTML = spanEl.querySelector('h1').innerText;
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-link{
  border:1px solid green;
  display:block

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link" href="#resA" id="resourceLinkA"><span>abc</span></a>
```

Comment: Did you try it in Chrome?

Comment: Very close, just need a way to make nit dynamic instead of tied to one hard coded Link ID

Comment: @epascarello - No, for my customer it has to work in IE only